# Populate dropdown list dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to generate dynamic form based on the key of document fields and using `ng-if` attribute in AngularJS.

Ex:

```
- If field name is "name|string" then populate textfield
- If field name is "name|select" then populate dropdownlist
- If field name is "name|datepicker" then populate datepicker
```

Following is the code:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(index, formVal) in providerModelData"  ng-if="!$first">                    
        <label>{{mySplit(index,0) | uppercase}}</label>
        <div ng-if="!mySplit(index,1)">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="providerModelData[index]">
        </div>
        <div ng-if="mySplit(index,1) == 'datepicker'">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="providerModelData[index]">            
        </div>
                <div ng-if="mySplit(index,1) == 'select'">                        
        <select class="form-control" ng-init="getDropdownData(index,colName)" ng-options="dropdown._id for dropdown in dropdownData[colName]">                
            <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.mySplit = function(string, nb) {
            var array = string.split('|');
            return array[nb];
        }
```

`textfields` are working fine and populating data but I'm facing issue while populating dropdown fields.

Example: I've two dropdown fields in my mongodb document i.e. `city|select` and `state|select`

I'm trying to use `ng-options` to call function by passing index and colName (document name) to populate dropdownlist but its not working.

Following is the code:

```
    $scope.dropdownData = {};
        $scope.getDropdownData = function (query, colName) {
            $http.get('/getdropdowndata/', {
                params: {
                    query: query,
                    colName: colName
                }
            }).success(function (response) {

                $scope.dropdownData[colName] = response;                    

            });
        };
```

Express:

```
router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {    
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;
    console.log(query.query);
    db.collection(query.colName).aggregate([{
        "$group":{
            "_id":"$"+query.query
            }
        }],function (err, docs) {        
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Initially I tried calling function in `ng-repeat` but it was going into infine loop. Then later I tried `ng-init` options but it only calls or initialize once which is not working in my case. Here I need to call function dynamically and based on that I want to populate dropdown for different fields.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is with `"dropdown._id for dropdown in getDropdownData(index,colName)"`. `getDropdownData` is a function, not a collection. You need to save the result of that function call to a scope variable, and use that variable for the `ng-options`

Comment: How can I use $scope variable in angular expression? Bcoz I'm calling function from my `view` not from controller

Comment: Can you provide a JSBin or Codepen with your code , what happens when you hard code the response of server I. getDropDownApi without sending a request and accepting it from server  ??

Comment: If you could provide the structure of response from the server and internals of providerModelData with each of the request and response structure it will be helpful..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it myself. Thanks @Rishab777 and @yarons for guiding me.

Here's the view code:

```
    <div ng-if="mySplit(index, 1) == 'select'">                     
        <select class="form-control">                
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option ng-model="providerModelData[index]" ng-selected="providerModelData[index]" ng-repeat="dropdown in dropdownData[index]" value="{{dropdown._id}}">{{dropdown._id}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

and controller:

```
        $scope.showModal = false;
        $scope.toggleModal = function (colId, colName) {
            $http.get('/collectiondata/' + colId + '/collectionName/' + colName).success(function (response) {
                $scope.colName = colName;
                $scope.colId = colId;

                for (var key in response) {
                    if (response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if ($scope.mySplit(key, 1) === 'select') {                                
                            $scope.getDropdownData(key, colName);     
                        }
                    }
                }

                $scope.providerModelData = response;
                $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
            });
        };

        $scope.dropdownData = {};

        $scope.getDropdownData = function (query, colName) {
            $http.get('/getdropdowndata/', {
                params: {
                    query: query,
                    colName: colName
                }
            }).success(function (response) {                    
                $scope.dropdownData[query] = response;
            });
        };
```

Now the issue is `ng-selected="providerModelData[index]"` is not working and its showing last item as selected only.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following solution:
In your controller, set up a variable for the dropdown data:

```
$scope.dropdownData = {};
```

Then change your `getDropdownData` function to:

```
$scope.getDropdownData=function(query, colName){                    
    $http.get('/getdropdowndata/', {
        params: {
            query: query,
            colName:colName
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        $scope.dropdownData[colName] = response; // This will put data into our html file
    });
}
```

And the HTML for your dropdown case should be:

```
<div ng-if="mySplit(index,1) == 'select'">                                    
    <select class="form-control" ng-init="getDropdownData(index,colName)" ng-options="dropdown._id for dropdown in dropdownData[colName]">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I used the notorious [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to make the call from getting data for the server. Perhaps there's a better way that I didn't consider. But in any case, the idea is to make the call to the server, and save the data in a way that you can fetch it easily from the view.

#### Edit

I don't know why, but for some reason this solution doesn't work with `ng-options`. It does, however, work when using it like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="getDropdownData(index,colName)">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="dropdown in dropdownData[colName]" value="dropdown._id">{{dropdown._id}}</option>
</select>
```

See a simple example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MqgnLYi8GzVEnjU88YbL?p=preview).

Comment: I tried this but not working. dropdown not populating data

Comment: have you tried debugging your angular code to verify the the `getDropdownData` function is being called?

Comment: Yes function is getting called and returns object but not populating data in dropdownlist

Comment: In my answer, I initialized `$scope.dropdownData` with an empty object `{}`. You initialized yours with an empty array.

Comment: This is my array for city: `[ { _id: 'LA' }, { _id: 'LA' }, { _id: 'Denver' }, { _id: 'LR' } ]`  and this for state `[ { _id: 'Arizona' } { _id: 'California' }, { _id: 'Arizona' } ]`. Is array format correct?

Comment: No. No error on console. Only blank dropdown populating

Comment: Oops sorry. Now I'm getting this error `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

Comment: but not sure whether its related to `ng-options` or not but on console its display 3 times

Comment: Yes its related to it becoz when I'm commenting `select` then its not showing error

Comment: That error is only coming when I'm doing `alert(JSON.stringify(response));`

Comment: Its working but its populating same date on `city` and `state` field

Comment: I've two different JSON for `city` and `state`. So I thing `ng-init` when it initializing city json then its populating both city json data in both dropdown and next time when I refresh page its initializing state data and populating state data in both dropdown

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your view is completely messed up as far I see it you are missing

```
ng-model
```

for your select input.

Your JSON is improper its missing `,` before `{'id_':'Arizona'}`

Try to get response in your controller and push it to array and make use of that array in your View :

```
$scope.getDropdownData=function(query, colName){                    
$http.get('/getdropdowndata/', {
    params: {
        query: query,
         colName:colName
    }
  }).success(function (response) {
      var returnArray = [];
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
      angular.ForEach(response,function(option){
      //parse response and push it to returnArray
        returnArray.push(option);
     });
       return returnArray;
  });
}
```

View :

```
   <div class="form-group">
     <select class="form-control" ng-model="selection" ng-options="dropdown._id for dropdown in  getDropDownData()">
     <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Here is the link to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Rishii/pen/bpozPL)
.

Comment: yes , but can you provide a sample of what you're getting from the server and does the above solution work ??

Comment: I've tried @yarons solution but its not populating data in dropdown list

Comment: This is what I'm getting from server
`[ { _id: 'LA' },
  { _id: 'LA' },
  { _id: 'Denver' },
  { _id: 'LR' } ]
[ { _id: 'Arizona' }
  { _id: 'California' },
  { _id: 'Arizona' } ]`

Comment: this is a invalid json missing comma before { _id: 'Arizona' } ??

Comment: Its getting generated from `mongodb/express`

Comment: The first json is for city and second is for state

Comment: Ito doesn't matter your JSON is wrong the way youre contructing it is wrong
You may have to refer this before going further 
http://json.org/
Get data from server in this format and try 
[{"state1":"city1"},{"state2":"city2"},{"state3":"city3"}]

Comment: How can I write `ng-options` in this case?

Comment: Please check modified code i.e. `ng-options` as per the ans by @yarons

Comment: Actually these are two different `JSON`

Comment: This is my json for city: `[ { _id: 'LA' }, { _id: 'LA' }, { _id: 'Denver' }, { _id: 'LR' } ]` and this for state `[ { _id: 'Arizona' } { _id: 'California' }, { _id: 'Arizona' } ]`

Comment: I've two `JSON` which I'm getting dynamically from mongodb by calling `getdropdownData(index, colName)` method. Here `index` is the field name of document i.e. city dropdown and `colName` is the name of collection. Same goes for `state` dropdown. So actually there can be multiple dropdowns at time which should fetch data based on its field name which I'm passing through `index` parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108148/discussion-between-mark-and-rishab777).

Comment: Please check my answer